# Restart From A Failed Jenkins Pipeline Stage

Tags: jenkins

In `Jenkins`, i have a `pipeline` with `stages`

1. **checkout** from `git`
2. **compile** create the binary
3. **integrate tests** which generate junit report xml

if `stage` 3 failed, I want to allow user to re-run `stage` 3 without `stage` 1, and 2. Currently, when I try to restart from `stage` 3 from `Jenkins` web gui, it reports the binary no longer exists. Look like some clean up process has been executed?

Comment: Are you using Maven ? Can you post your pipeline file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple nodes or execute the pipeline concurrently Jenkins might not look in the same directory in which you compiled the binary. You can use the [`archiveArtifacts`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts) step in stage 2 and [`copyArtifacts`](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) in stage 3 for continuity (for performance considerations you can set a variable in stage 2 and run `copyArtifacts` only when it's not set in stage 3.)